# Conkeror as default browser on Mac OS 10.6

Tags: settings, web-browsing

I'd like to use [Conkeror](http://conkeror.org/) as default browser in Mac OS 10.6. Selecting conkeror.app as default browser with Safari does not work. While it is possible to start Conkeror via Firefox command line arguments (-app), opening additional URLs with that instance is not.

If anyone has been able to setup Conkeror on Mac OS 10.6 in a way that...

- uses Conkeror as default browser for all applications
- reuses a running Conkeror instance when opening an URL (either current or new buffer)

..., could you post the steps necessary to do so?

P.S.: Feel free to retag with 'conkeror'

EDIT: In addition to the Info.plist solution posted below, you also need the line

url_remoting_fn = load_url_in_new_buffer

in your .conkerorrc, if you want to open URLs in an existing window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible to set Conkeror as the default web browser; it just needs a properly structured `Info.plist` file.

I created one here: http://www.markdouma.com/developer/ConkerorInfoPlist.zip

Just download that, unzip it, and replace the following `Info.plist` file with the one included in the download:

`/Applications/conkeror.mozdev.org/conkeror/Contents/Info.plist`

Note: after completing this, make sure you `touch` the application bundle, which will force Launch Services to re-examine and re-register the app and its newly found capability for the `http://` and `https://` URL types. In other words, the following should be sufficient:

`touch /Applications/conkeror.mozdev.org/conkeror.app`

Then deselect and re-select the app icon in the Finder.

Launch Safari, and choose Conkeror from the popup menu:

[image]

FWIW, I changed the Info.plist to be the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>CONK</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>org.mozdev.conkeror</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>Web site URL</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>http</string>
                <string>https</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>xulrunner</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>conkeror</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>93</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>(c) 2007, Shawn Betts</string>
    <key>NSAppleScriptEnabled</key>
    <true/>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>Conkeror</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>0.9.3</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string>Conkeror 0.9.3, A 100% keyboard driven mozilla based web browser.</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

Select Conkerer as your default through Safari's preferences.

Update per the comment: From their [website](http://conkeror.org/InstallationOSX): "Unfortunately, at this time, there doesn't seem to be a way on OSX to configure conkeror as your default browser. " I just happened to stumble across that. I had never heard of Conkerer until now.

Comment: Sorry, was meant to say "... with Safari ..." instead of "... with Opera ...". Edited above, thanks anyway.

Comment: I gotta say I’ve never heard of that thing before. I thought you meant Konqueror from KDE, but then I saw it has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

springify, it's not possible to set conkeror as the default browser on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [Default App](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/)? It's a preference pane you can install to set any app as a default for a number of different tasks.

It's running on my Macbook running 10.6, and let's me choose any app I want for browsers; I don't have Conkerer but I can only assume it'd work for that too. Worth a download anyway.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So under the hood, Workgroup Manager creates a plist located at...

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.internet.plist

Which contains this information...

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>mcx_defaultWebBrowser</key>
    <string>/Applications/Google Chrome.app</string>
</dict>
</plist>`

So create that file and change "/Applications/Google Chrome.app" to whatever the path of your application is. Hopefully that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try [Choosy](http://www.choosyosx.com/).